# SQL join: three tables, one of them is the relationship between the other two and rows may not exist

Tags: sql, left-join

I have three tables:

products (p_id, prod_name),
competitors (c_id, comp_name),
sells (p_id, c_id, price).

So let's say I have the data:

```
(producs table)
p_id | prod_name
1    | product1
2    | product2

(competitors table)
c_id | comp_name
1    | competitor1

(sells table)
p_id | c_id | price
1    | 1    | 1.56
```

Using c_id = 1 somewhere, I wanted to retrieve:

```
prod_name | price
product1  | 1.56
product2  | NULL
```

The problem is table sells is the only relashionship between product and competitors. And table sells may not have a row with the product id and competitor id. in this case, I want it to return null as the price.
In a nutshell, I want to return all the products for a given competitor (let's say, comp_id = 1), with it's price or null if the row does not exist in table sells.

I tried this, but it didn't work, as this did not return the NULL price:

```
SELECT prod_name, price
  FROM products
  LEFT JOIN sells ON products.p_id = sells.p_id
  LEFT JOIN competitors ON sells.c_id = competitors.c_id
 WHERE competitors.c_id = 1
```

How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: I was wrong earlier. What you actually want is a `cross join between Competitors and Products` followed by a `left join to Sells on Competitors.c_id = Sells.c_id and Products.p_id = Sells.p_id` and `where Competitors.c_id = 1`.

Comment: Nikola, I don't know how, but you not only solved my problem in my proposed database but you solved my problem in my current database as well. Thanks a lot, man. I'm grateful to everyone for helping me, but somehow your comment was the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b83d3/6)):

```
select prodname, price
from products p
left join sells s
  on p.pid = s.pid
left join competitors c
  on s.cid = c.cid
where c.cid = 1 
  or c.cid is null
```

Comment: thanks, I've looked at it. But it didn't work in my postgre server. Gonna have a look at my tables, to see if anything is wrong...

Comment: Ok, I copied your code in another postgre database and it worked... thanks again... the problem lies im my current database...

Answer (score 1):

```
select prod_name, price 
from products 
left join sells 
    on products.p_id = sells.p_id 
left join competitors 
    on sells.c_id = competitors.c_id 
AND competitors.c_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it didn't work as it is returning prices from all competitors and did not return the null price...

Answer (score 0):

You want a right join to competitors instead of a left join. A right join will return all records in the right table regardless of if there are any in the left table; this is the opposite of how left join behaves.

Comment: Thanks, but this way won't I get all competitors? I want results from just one competitor. Something like: cmopetitor1 sells product1 for $1.56, and price for product2 is not set.

Comment: @user1531978 Ekolis is right, replace all left joins with right ones and see the difference. Actually, it might be better to keep left joins (as they are easily visualized) and swap the tables around, starting with `competitors`.

Comment: Thanks, Nikola, I switched the left joins with the right joins. But I still can't get that null price... I'm starting to guess the problem lies in something else...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.prod_name, s.price
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN sells s ON p.p_id = s.p_id
WHERE s.c_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't return the null price... Unless pgAdmin III is not showing null values...

Comment: it just returns product1 | 1.56